# Give Sum for matching Column and Row values - repeating variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The first table below shows how much each person owes and who pays it (it's part of a larger model so I simplified it for our purposes here).

Our goal in the second table below is to give a sum when both the column and row value match.

For example: A (column C) paid $244.17 (D36:H48) in expenses for B (row 35).

Where am I wrong here? I have tried different methods suggested here.

[image: Table]

Comment: Off-topic, by the way, this app [Settle Up](https://settleup.io/) does what you want in excel. Just in case

Comment: Thanks, @DavidLeal but this is part of a financial reporting we have. I simply dumbed it down for StackOverflow to get the concept. I have other simple apps as well. :)

Comment: You should use `SUMPRODUCT` as in `=SUMPRODUCT($D$36:$H$48*($D$35:$H$35=D$52)*($C$36:$C$48=$C54))`. See [this site](https://exceljet.net/formulas/sum-matching-columns-and-rows)

Comment: @PeterT this is the first formula I used from google but keep getting #VALUE error. I made sure that column and row headers are the same to eliminate if that is causing any issue.

Comment: I recreated your data in the exact same rows and columns, but I'm not getting the `#VALUE!` error. But I use the `SUMIFS` formula you've shown, I do get that error.

Comment: I tested the approach @PeterT suggested and it works

Comment: sumproduct lacks parsimony - see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another alternative, that only requires to extend the formula down, but not to the left, because on each row it returns an array with all column values. In cell `I3` enter the following formula:

```
=MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$A$15=H3)),IF($B$3:$F$15="", 0, $B$3:$F$15))
```

or using `LET` to avoid repetition of the same range:

```
=LET(set, $B$3:$F$15, MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$A$15=H3)),IF(set="", 0, set))
```

**Notes**:

- `MMULT` only works with numeric values, so empty cells need to be converted.
- You can replace `TRANSPOSE` with `TOROW` if you want.
- `$`-notation is not required in `H3`, because we extend the formula only *down*

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

**Note**: This solution assumes header values to compare are the same, i.e. same values for **Paid For** (`I2:M2`) and **Paid By** (`H3:H7`). Which is the most common situation. That is why in the formula only **Paid By** column is used. If that is not the case, then the solution provided by @JB-007 is more flexible, because the values can be different, but then you need to extend the formula in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

screenshot/s [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9g4lpIH-V93KbUWap9g?e=gLVhm7) refer:

```
=SUM($C$4:$E$6*($C$3:$E$3=C$8)*($B$4:$B$6=$B9))
```

(sumifs will really struglly to work across different dimensions)

PS - as you'll see most will advise sumproduct - I think it's overdue deprecation because there's very little (if anything) you can do with sumproduct that you cannot with sum.  You can even do counts with sum SUM(1*($C$3:$E$3=C$8)*($B$4:$B$6=$B9))) returns the count of where these values are equivalent...

*Save yourself the extra seven letters over and over!* ☺

[image: SAMPLE]

Comment: With Excel updates that most of the functions work in array fashion `SUM` can emulate most of the `SUMPRODUCT` functionality. The only difference I would say is that with `SUMPRODUCT` you can use other arithmetic operation, but this is confusing anyway. I am not aware of any other scenario. I am agreed with you.

Comment: Occasionally the fact that `SUMPRODUCT`'s *array* arguments ignore non-numerics can be useful. For example, with `B1:B10` containing a mixture of numerics and non-numerics, `=SUMPRODUCT(N(A1:A10="X"),B1:B10)` will return a value, whereas `=SUM((A1:A10="X")*B1:B10)` will error (as will the *product* form of `SUMPRODUCT`: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10="X")*B1:B10)`). The `SUM` formula would have to be amended to include `ISNUMBER` or some error function, else adapted to `=SUM((A1:A10="X")*N(+B1:B10))`, though this last is not so intuitive.

Comment: all agreed hence the caveat "very little (if anything)" - it's like the ongoing debate RE: index vs vlookup (notwithstanding the advent of xlookup in 365 etc.) - of course index is superior - in almost every circumstance except when you actually need / want the 'fuzzy find'/'nearest' lookup feature vlookup's final argument provides...  I'm just saying - use sumproduct on the v. odd (bizarre) occasion when there is something it might offer - but to blindly use it for everything - seems wasteful - and 'non-intuitive' is a copy out - once you start thinking that way, it 
*becomes* intuitive.

Comment: The one thing I wish either of these (sum/sumproduct) did was to allow for spill type calcs - heck I think you can even incoprorate that in a countifs but not the sumifs - thee must be a reason duh like "how would excel know when you wanted to calculate the overall sum or a sum per row/spill dimension? who cares - we can put man in space you telling me they can't figure out a way - through a double hash tag in front or something make a plan!  lol :)